# position of layers when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

when I'm resizing my browser-window the blue buttons go below the logo on the left, on the same line as the text "Welkom Bart" although they are two different layers. I want the text "Welkom Bart" to lower as well, so they are not on the same line. What do I need to add to my css?

[image: normal]
[image: sized]

html e.g.

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <div id="logo"><img ... /></div>
    <div id="usermenu">Buttons</div>
</div>

<div id="maintitle">
    <h2>Welkom Bart</h2>
    <hr />
</div>
```

css

```
#mainmenu {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#usermenu {
    float: right;
}
#maintitle {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#maintitle hr {
    color: #56c2e1;
    display: block; 
    height: 1px;
    border: 0; 
    border-top: 1px solid #56c2e1;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding word-wrap: break-word; to your css?

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:both` to `#maintitle` =)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` to `#mainmenu`. This will cause its height to include all floated elements, such as your `#usermenu` element, allowing flow to continue underneath it.

Comment: if I add overflow:hidden to #mainmenu, all of the buttons just dissapear when resizing.

Comment: Ah, that's because you set a fixed `height` on it. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div id="maintitle" style="width:100%">
<h2>Welkom Bart</h2>
<hr />
```